# TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable when using flask_jwt_extended int RESTful API

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I'm building a REST API using flask. I'm using postman for testing a route that creates a new item in my database, but only if the user is logged in. The routes for registering and login are working well, the last one returns the token using flask_jwt_extended module. When I send a post request to my "/api/notes" (creates a new note in database) I get the error bellow:

" (...) raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} '

TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable"

for the request I'm using the authorization tab of postman. type: Bearer Token, and my token in the field (tried with and without quotation marks)

I had faced this error this morning, before implementing my one-many relantionship, but I got it working by replacing my VERY_LONG_TOKEN with "VERY_LONG_TOKEN" in the Barear token field. I thought that because the token includes dots, it was interpreting as a function. But after implementing the relationship, I went to test and got this error again.

my note.py file:

```
from flask import request, Response, jsonify
from app.models import User, Note
from flask_restful import Resource
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, get_jwt_identity

class NotesApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        notes = Note.objects().to_json()
        return Response(notes, mimetype="application/json", status=200)

    @jwt_required  
    def post(self):  # post method I'm making a request for
        print("fool")  # this doesn't get printed  ->  not reaching 
        user_id = get_jwt_identity()
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        if data:
            user = User.objects(id=user_id) # logged in user
            note = Note(**data, user_author=user) # creates note with the author
            note.save()
            user.update(push__notes=note) # add this note to users notes
            user.save()
            id = str(note.id)
            return {'id': id}, 200
        else:
            return {'error': 'missing data'}, 400
```

my models.py:

```
from app import db  # using mongodb
from datetime import datetime
from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash

class Note(db.Document):
    title = db.StringField(max_length=120,required=True)
    content = db.StringField(required=True)
    status = db.BooleanField(required=True, default=False)
    date_modified = db.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
    user_author = db.ReferenceField('User')
    
class User(db.Document):
    username = db.StringField(max_length=100, required=True, unique=True)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=120, required=True, unique=True)
    password = db.StringField(required=True)
    remember_me = db.BooleanField(default=False)
    notes = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField('Note', reverse_delete_rule=db.PULL)) # one-many relationship

    def hash_password(self):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(self.password).decode('utf8')

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)


User.register_delete_rule(Note, 'user_author', db.CASCADE)
```

**init**.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config  # my config class to set MONGOBD_HOST and SECRET_CLASS
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = MongoEngine(app)
api = Api(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)

from app.resources.routes import initialize_routes
initialize_routes(api)
```

resources/routes.py:

```
from .note import NotesApi, NoteApi
from .auth import SignupApi, LoginApi

def initialize_routes(api):
    api.add_resource(NotesApi, '/api/notes')
    api.add_resource(NoteApi, '/api/note/<id>')
    api.add_resource(SignupApi, '/api/auth/signup')
    api.add_resource(LoginApi, '/api/auth/login')
```

folder structure:

```
app
  |_ resources
      |_ auth.py  # signup working well, login also working, return a token (type = String)
      |_ note.py
      |_ routes.py
  |_ __init__.py
  |_ models.py
config.py
appname.py  #just import app and do a app.run()
```

body of my post request:

```
{
   "title": "test0",
   "content": "test0"  
}
```

Did anyone faced it before or know how to solve it?

Edit: added more code info

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] please? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question adding more information. Thank you.

Comment: @WilianeSouza Where the app breaks at note.py file?

Comment: It wasn't pointing any line of my code in the traceback, but I fixed the issue based on Maylor's answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Looks like flask-jwt-extended released a new version over the weekend. As part of the API changes, the `@jwt_required` decorator is now `@jwt_required()`

https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/v4_upgrade_guide.html#api-changes

Comment: not sure why have you mentioned "jtw" instead of "jwt"

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution. IDE does not recognize sythax change in jwt extended.

Comment: Man, Thank you soo much.. I have been busting my .... you got the idea, I didn't knew that it was due to '()'.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the HTTP status codes, that worked for me. example

Replace:

```
return {'id': id}, 200
```

with:

```
return {'id': id}
```

or:

```
resp = jsonify({'id': id})

resp.status_code = 200

return resp
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).